# PHPUnit - tests if route hitting controller

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-8

i want to make a test that a route hitting a controller method as specified in the routes/web.php file.

for example the "page" route in the routes/web.php file is like this:

```
Route::get('/page', [PageController::class, 'page']);
```

I tried to code combined with a little bit code from someone in different QnA coding site, but the `factory()` and `actingAs()` function is always undefined. so far, my test code is like this:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use Carbon\Factory;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function Route_Home()
    {
        $user = factory(HomeController::class)->create();
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get("/page");
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

for the Laravel version, is Laravel 8.

edit:

i don't make a model for this one because my controller contain one function and the function is just return string like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function page()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

now I want to ask another question:
if my controller is like that and I don't use or make any models, am I should still use `factory()` and `create()`? and what is the good possible ways to write tests that ensuring the route is hitting the controller action?

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of a Unit test, you should use a feature test which can be created using `php artisan make:test PageControllerTest` or whichever name you would like.

Then, in order to create a user for testing routes, use
`App\Models\User::factory()->create()` but denote that you generally do *not* require a user for testing routes (only when a user is explicitly required for that route, for example when using the `auth` middleware or in the controller logic).

With that, you can continue your approach, i.e.

```php
$this->actingAs($user)->get("/page")->assertStatus(200);
```

And regarding your last question, I think it really depends what your controller is doing. If you know that your controller is responding with a `200` status code, then your approach is fine. Additionally, I would also check if the logic in your controller worked. For example when the controller inserts something in the database, you can perform assertions for that too, for example

```php
$this->assertDatabaseCount('users', 2);
```

For mor information regarding that, see the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing).

Comment: the controller (PageController) contains 1 function. the function is just returns a string like this `public function page() { return "Hello World";}` . do I still need `factory()` and `create()` to test it?

Comment: @shirazy it is the most important thing that you read the documentation before attempting anything, as the documentation should (and for Laravel it does) explain every feature it has. So, read [this part of the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests) as it is exactly explaining everything you need to know about how to test a Controller. Related to `factory` and `create` (`Model::factory()->create()`), you only use it if you need to `create` (store model data on the database) or `make` (just model with fake data but in memory, not in database), Check the docs that `simon` shared